endpoint en nest no me devuelve resultados ni me da error
Esto intentando realizar un endpoint para obtener la url de una imagen que tengo en firebase storage, me codigo obtiene bien la url(lo he comprobado con un console.log y se almacena bien en la variable url) pero al retornarla parece que falla, pues el endpoint se queda esperando respuestas cuando supuestamente ya ha terminado, soy nuevo con js, imagino que sea algun concepto basico referido a las promesas y las funciones asincronas, pero no encuentro la solucio, mi funcion en el controlador es la siguiente:
    @Get('/retrieval/:filename')
      async retrieval(@Param('filename') filename: string, @Res() response: Response){
        return this.firebaseService.retrieval(filename, response);
      }

mi funcion en el servicio es la siguiente:
async retrieval(filename: string, response: Response): Promise<string> {
      try{  
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const file = bucket.file(filename);
        const fileExists = await file.exists();
        if (!fileExists[0]) {
          throw new NotFoundException('Image not found');
        }
        const [url] = await file.getSignedUrl({  
          action: 'read',  
          expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60,
        });
        return url;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Could not get image');
    }
  }



Solución: remueve la inyección del objeto de respuesta response en la declaración de la función retrieval del controlador`.
Razón: Al inyectar el objeto de respuesta se le indica al framework que se quiere tomar el control manual de la respuesta y por eso la respuesta no finaliza automáticamente.

Gracias amigo, solucionado el problema, varias horas pensando que podria generar el problema y no se me ocurrio eliminar el response, pues nada, cosas de novatos
